# Variant timeseries postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, time

I have a problem that resembles an aggregation problem. My context is: I have a table with an event log and I want to apply some composition rules based on the attributes and time intervals that these events were created.

Example of a rule: I want to return the grouping of "VisitProduct" events that were created within 10 seconds, contain the same product_id, and have occurred at least 3 times during this period.

Example data:

```
+--------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
|     name     | actor |          created         |     properties    | event_id |
+--------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
| VisitProduct |   1   | 2019-02-24T20:25:31.446Z | {"product_id": 3} |     1    |
+--------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
| VisitProduct |   1   | 2019-02-24T20:25:35.446Z | {"product_id": 3} |     3    |
+--------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
| VisitProduct |   1   | 2019-02-24T20:25:39.446Z | {"product_id": 3} |     4    |
+--------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
| VisitProduct |   1   | 2019-02-24T20:25:40.446Z | {"product_id": 3} |     7    |
+--------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
| VisitProduct |   1   | 2019-02-24T20:25:43.446Z | {"product_id": 3} |    11    |
+--------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
| VisitProduct |   1   | 2019-02-24T20:25:48.446Z | {"product_id": 3} |    18    |
+--------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Example of output after query:

```
+-----------+
| event_ids |
+-----------+
|  1,3,4,7  |
+-----------+
```

As seen, from the event of id 1, it searched within the next 10 seconds if there were other events events with the same property, grouped and displayed them, because there were at least 3 occurrences in that interval.

The same event can not be grouped more than once, so the combinations (3,4,7,11) or (4,7,11,18) or (7,11,18) were not formed, since one of these events had already been grouped before.

My main problem is that the 10 second window is not a fixed window because it will always fetch from the creation date of a first event if 2 other events with the same product_id property were created in this range.

What is the best way to solve this kind of problem in postgresql?

Comment: The best way is the same way as with any other sql problem. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sample data, desired results (both as text tables), and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of examples. Thanks for the feedback and I'm waiting to see if it's clearer now with the examples above.

Comment: I think now all the information has been made more explicit.